# WCF Service - The request channel timed out- Increasing timeout has no effect

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, wcf, time-out

Consuming a WCF service that downloads a large amount of data from a Sharepoint2010 List.

I wrote a test client (using inbuilt automated tests in VS 2010). When I invoke the service method, I get

> System.TimeoutException: The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:00:59.9511700. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.

On my client, the (app.config) configuration is as follows:

```
 <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_SalesInfoServiceContract"
                closeTimeout="00:12:00" openTimeout="00:12:00" receiveTimeout="00:12:00"
                sendTimeout="00:12:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
                hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
          maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
            realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
```

I've increased the timeout, and increased the max buffer size.

The web.config is as follows:

```
<service name="XXX.WebServices.SalesInfo.SalesInfo" behaviorConfiguration="SalesInfoServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="XXX.WebServices.SalesInfo.ISalesInfo" />
    <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
  </service>
  <behavior name="SalesInfoServiceBehavior">
      <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
        <defaultPorts>
          <add scheme="http" port="9083" />
        </defaultPorts>
      </useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646" /> <== Tried adding this tag
    </behavior>
```

If i directly instantiate the service class, the method works - so i know my logic is right. It takes about 1m:45s.

Any ideas what other timeout i need to increase?

Comment: Can you show more of your Server and Client configurat? Like which protocol you are using? Ops, did not read propperly see the binding now. :)

Answer (score 1):

Robban1980, good suggestion, went down that path, but realized problem was on my client side.

My client was ignoring my app.config (not sure why)

I eventually worked around the problem by setting the timeouts in code like this:

```
 SalesInfoServiceServiceContractClient client = new SalesInfoServiceServiceContractClient();
((BasicHttpBinding)client.Endpoint.Binding).MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
((BasicHttpBinding)client.Endpoint.Binding).MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
foreach (OperationDescription op in client.Endpoint.Contract.Operations)
{
    var dataContractBehavior = op.Behaviors.Find<DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior>();
    if (dataContractBehavior != null)
    {
        //do this else you get error about limitations on number of objects that can be deserialized
        dataContractBehavior.MaxItemsInObjectGraph = int.MaxValue; 
    }
}
client.Endpoint.Binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 30);

// rest of the client
SalesInfoDataItems items= client.GetSalesData(XXX);
client.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

On your client-side, you have increased the timeout settings but you have not done so on your server-side.

try adding something like this to your server-side basicHttpBinding (and if your operation takes 1 hour and 45 minutes you probably need to increase the send/receive timeouts on the client too)

```
<endpoint address="" 
    binding="basicHttpBinding" 
    bindingConfiguration="myBindingConfiguration" 
    contract="XXX.WebServices.SalesInfo.ISalesInfo" />

<bindings>
 <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="myBindingConfiguration" 
           receiveTimeout="02:00:00"
           sendTimeout="02:00:00"
           openTimeout="00:12:00"
           closeTimeout="00:12:00">
          <security mode="None" />
     </binding>
 </basicHttpBinding>
```

Reference:

For details refer to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731361(v=vs.110).aspx) article.

Comment: Thanks, i'll give this a shot. And i'm a doofus. I meant to say the operation takes 1:45, not 1:45:00. Edited.